# Android reversing-can not see my loaded so file in the maps file

Tags: android, apk, loadlibrary, reversing

During the APK execution the application loads SO file via JAVA loadLibrary API.
The procedure succeeded and it ran the the SO code.
Analyzing the `/proc/PID/maps` file of the process does not show the SO loaded file!

The SO file haven't unloaded or something like this!
How is it possible?

1. I tried to Hook the loadLibrary API to see that it indeed loaded- Yes it is.
2. I tried to play with the application to see that that the functionality that uses
   the SO file is works.
3. I tried to hook some JNI functions of the SO file using Frida, but it can not find the SO file!.